# Related to function and recursion

Tags: c

This is a code by my teacher for printing pattern using recursion.
Why is "Are you Here " printed ? I can't understand the outer loop. Please Help!

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int display (int n)
{   

    printf("\nFunctionCalled\n");
    if (n==-1)
    {
        return n;
    }

    else 
    {   

        display (n-1);


         printf("Are You Here ");


        for (int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        printf("\n");

        return n;    // where is this value being returned ??

    }

}
```

Comment: Hey! I see no main function?!?

Comment: watch how many times FunctionCalled is printed when you pass -2 :)

Comment: Why not ask your teacher? It is **his** job to explain. Find out yourself by using a debugger and single-step.

Comment: Yess That's running infinitely!

Comment: Why my value of n increasing after every return n statement ?  The teacher isn't available .

Comment: @Mr.X lets say you call the function with n=3, you will continuously add n-1 to the stack until you reach -1, so your stack becomes (simplified) 3-2-1-0-(-1), as you return the values get popped off the stack, so you return (-1) then 0 then 1 then 2 then 3

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick . That was really helpful sir . Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the application is first called in your main function, it expects a return value.  Unless the `n` that you pass to it is -1, the lines following the self-invoked function will happen once because it is called in `main` and has to reach the end of the function.  When the self-invoked function returns a number, that doesn't end the function call to `display` in `main`, the last `return n;` in your `else` block does.

Recursion is easiest to understand when followed step-by-step.  So I would recommend doing that to fully understand it.

Comment: Why my value of n increasing after every return n statement ?

Comment: @Mr.X @Ryan.Fitzpatrick explained it pretty well above.  Run through it step by step.  It's decreasing each time (or appearing as such) because you're calling `display` with n-1 recursively, so it's going to display *s for each `n`, starting with `n`, then `n-1`, then `(n -1) -1`, etc. until `n - 1` is equal to `-1`.

Comment: ! Thank you so much !